# Using FFmpeg, How to convert an frame image sequence to video(video codec : dvvideo)?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-codecs

I'm working on an image processing project.

The project proceeds as follows:

Input Video -> frame Sequence -> (Processing) -> Output Video

I want to create the output video with the same specifications as the input video.

The specs of the input video we use are:

```
- Size : 1280x1080, Codec : dvvideo, pixel_fmt : yuv422
```

But I am struggling with the following error:

```
Duration: 00:00:03.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 1280x1080 [SAR 3:2 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 29.97 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> dvvideo (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[dvvideo @ 0x55b965b745c0] DVCPRO HD encoding is not supported.
[dvvideo @ 0x55b965451780] ff_frame_thread_encoder_init failed
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

The code is below. (subprocess in python)

```
ffmpeg -y -f image2 -r "{fps}" -i {input_img_root} -s 1280:1080 -b:v {bit_rate}  -vcodec dvvideo -pix_fmt yuv422p "{output}"
```

(fps and bitrate are taken from the input video. and input_img_root and output are paths.)

I've been trying for several days, but it doesn't work.

If you know any way to make a new video while maintaining the video specifications (Especially dvvideo codec)(not using ffmpeg), it would be nice to share it.

Comment: You're hiding too much info behind python variables (as to what you actually commanded ffmpeg to do) but one error is `-s 1280:1080` which needs to read `-s 1280x1080`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

This problem was due to the version of FFmpeg.

After upgrading the version of FFmpeg to 4.4.2(latest version), the error disappeared.